# Running a batch does not reliably change the Theme on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, slideshow, desktop

We are working on a program which will cycle the desktop of a Windows 7, which we do by modifying a text document to have the correct Theme information, converting it to a Windows 7 .theme file, and executing a .bat which is supposed to run the .theme file.

Every part of this works as expected and reliably, except for some reason the .theme file does not run, even when the .bat file executes.

Here is what the java portion looks like, which launches the .bat file:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(WORKINGDIR + "\\src\\Themes\\changer.bat");

p.waitFor();
```

And here is the .bat file:

```
echo off
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"%~dp0cur.theme"

taskkill /im explorer.exe /f 
start "" "C:\windows\explorer.exe"
```

Everything else works correctly, and you can launch the theme in the standard way (clicking on it) just fine, but the batch doesnt reliably launch the theme.

Comment: Are you intentionally commenting the rundll32.exe from executing

Comment: Oops, no but In the actual batch it is uncommented. I'll edit the post